# When does dynamic_cast return 0 and when throws exception? cpp

Tags: c++

In this link:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

> When dynamic_cast cannot cast a pointer because it is not a complete
>   object of the required class -as in the second conversion in the
>   previous example- it returns a null pointer to indicate the failure.
>   If dynamic_cast is used to convert to a reference type and the
>   conversion is not possible, an exception of type bad_cast is thrown
>   instead.

I couldnt understand from this text part, what are the exact conditions when dinamic_cast returns a null ptr, and when exception has been thrown.

If someone can please show me a two code samples that one of them return null ptr and the other is throwing an exception, it will be very appriciate. thanks.

Comment: What in particular is unclear? It returns a `nullptr` in case of casting pointers, and throws an exception in case of casting references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the difference:

```
DerivedClass *der = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(someBaseClassPtr);
```

Will return `nullptr` in the case where `someBaseClassPtr` does not refer to an object of `DerivedClass`.

```
DerivedClass& der = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass&>(someBaseClassObj);
```

Will throw an exception if `someBaseClassObj` does not in fact reference an object of `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 2):

If the failed cast is to a pointer, a null pointer is returned; if it is to a reference, then an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Fang possibly the OP has issues with English reading comprehension

Comment: @Brian sometimes, masters of English but beginners in C++ forget there is no such a thing as a `nullref` (the equiv of a `*nullptr`)

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` will also return `null_ptr` if the none of the base classes have a virtual method. It has no `VTable` to work with. Best practice is to declare the `destructor` of the base-est class as virtual.